# Identifying a child element of a clicked target in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to work out how I can right-click anywhere in the table, which has an event listener on the `tr` tag, and will pass the `click()` command down to the child `button`.

```js
jQuery(".catcher").contextmenu(function (e) {
    e.target.**FIND CHILD BUTTON**.click();
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="catcher">
    <td>
      <span>
          <button onclick="alert('it works!');">Button</button>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use jquery `find` method wich searches for first child instance at any depth

```js
jQuery(".catcher").contextmenu(function(e) {
  $(this).find('button').click();
  return false;
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="catcher">
    <td>
      <span>
          <button onclick="alert('it works!');">Button</button>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
jQuery(".catcher").contextmenu(function (e) {
    //e.target.**FIND CHILD BUTTON**.click();
  $(e.target).find('button').click()
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="catcher">
    <td>
      <span>
          <button onclick="alert('it works!');">Button</button>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

wrap `e.target` in `$()` then use `.find('button')`

Answer (score 0):

Refer this here Qty is Class Name

```
($(e).parent().parent().find(".Qty").val()
```