# How to get text of next td in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need Test 2 text when I clicked on "Click". I have tried like this ...

```
$("#clicked").click(function(){
  alert( $('this').closest('td').next('td').next('td').text());
})
```

But In alert there is empty. How I can get Test 2 ?

```
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td><a id = 'clicked'>Click</a></td>
  <td>Test 1</td>
  <td><a id = 'clicked2' /> Test 2</a></td>
</tr>
```

---

*From comment below:*

`this` means `$('#clicked')`. That means when I clicked on the `Click` link.

Comment: What's $(this) for you?

Comment: Where's your click handler? Is your entire script that one line?

Comment: $(this).parent().next().next().text();

Comment: Note that your second `a` element shouldn't have the `/` in the opening tag.

Comment: `$('#clicked').on('click', function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('td').next('td').next('td').text());
});`

Comment: @Riad: Why? That looks basically the same.

Comment: @Mohibul: You need to give a full example of your issue before your question is closed. Posting one line and having everyone guess what the problem may be isn't enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38650371/indentifying-a-child-element-of-a-clicked-target-in-jquery/38650881#38650881

Comment: Now your `this` is in quotes. Is your actual code like that? If so, that's your issue. If not, your code should work as is. Since you keep changing things, I have a feeling your *actual* code is different. Is that right?

Answer (score 3):

you need to use `parent` instead of `closest` :

```
$("#clicked").click(function(){
  text = $(this).parent().next('td').next('td').text();
  alert(text);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g6gnog4h/

Comment: *"you need to use parent instead of closest"* Why do you say that? That's not correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#clicked').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).closest('td').next().text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, as you need to go parent tr and than find the 4th td with the ID of a tag to get the text.

```
<table><tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td><a id = 'clicked'>Click</a></td>
  <td>Test 1</td>
  <td><a id = 'clicked2' /> Test 2</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
$('#clicked').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parents('tr').children().find('#clicked2').text());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try like this:

```
$('#clicked').click(function(){
  var val=$(this).siblings().text();
  alert(val);
});
```

siblings() method returns all sibling elements of the selected element.